# Xamarin.forms - Login page with Navigation to Master Detail page has a weird layout

Tags: android, authentication, xamarin, navigation

I have an app that features a login page which starts up when you open the app. Once you are in the main page, it has a master-detail page to display the data. The problem is the weird layout. The navigation page is on top of the master-detail page.  Like this:[image]

here is the code for the login

```
public partial class LoginPage : ContentPage
           {
                public LoginPage ()
                {
                    InitializeComponent ();
                }
                async void OnSignUpButtonClicked (object sender, EventArgs e)
                {
                    await Navigation.PushAsync (new SignUpPage ());
                }

                async void OnLoginButtonClicked (object sender, EventArgs e)
                {
                    var user = new User {
                        Username = usernameEntry.Text,
                        Password = passwordEntry.Text
                    };

                    var isValid = AreCredentialsCorrect (user);
                    if (isValid) {
                        App.IsUserLoggedIn = true;
                        Navigation.InsertPageBefore (new MainPage (), this);
                        await Navigation.PopToRootAsync ();
                    } else {
                        messageLabel.Text = "Login failed";
                        passwordEntry.Text = string.Empty;
                    }
                }

                bool AreCredentialsCorrect (User user)
                {
                    return user.Username == Constants.Username && user.Password ==    Constants.Password;
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This code looks overly complex, and I've seen similar patterns cause rendering problems with Xamarin.Forms:

```
            Navigation.InsertPageBefore (new MainPage (), this);
            await Navigation.PopToRootAsync ();
```

Since the current page is known to be the first and only page on the navigation stack (from what I can tell), this should be sufficient:

```
            Application.Current.MainPage = new MainPage ();
```

If it weren't the only page on the navigation stack, you would want to pop the navigation stack first (though not on Android -- this causes problems):

```
            if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.iOS) {
                await Navigation.PopToRootAsync ();
            }
            Application.Current.MainPage = new MainPage ();
```

Comment: THANK YOU!, I was finding a simpler solution like directing it instead of adding navigations. It works.